# Porting VS 2015 to VS 2017 MSB8020: The build tools for v140 unresolved issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, porting

Okay Folks I have an issue.  I had hoped I would find the answer in the forums but none seems to be exactly what I need.

Brand new computer, Just installed VS2017 (never updated from 2015 on the prior computer because I worried about problems like this).

Been working on this software for about a year. It has 2 libraries, 3 project files total.

Now all single project Solutions are building perfectly (No Issues).  The Solution with 3 Project files Solution is generating a error of; MSB8020: Build Tools for v140.  NOW I'm not trying to go backwards - so answers like install v140 (found on previous questions) is out of the question.

ISOLATING THE ISSUE - Library (A) has no dependencies.  Library (B) depends on Library (A). The Main Code (Project) uses both.  When I build library (A) - No error - When I build Library (B) - the MSB9020 error appears.

I verified references in the project files are v141 and verified in project properties.  IS IT POSSIBLE - something in the code is forcing this - The code is nothing fancy (for debugging purposes down the road).  No fancy directives.

I can continue on the old computer to work on this project.  What I'm considering is rebuilding the Projects from scratch.  I was trying to avoid that.

ANY IDEAS you have would be GREATLY Appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Project > Properties > General.  Change the Platform ToolSet to v141.

Comment: Thanks Hans - Tried that - Actually I used that on the other programs I ported over. THANK YOU! (When I tried that on the 3 projects - even went so far as to do each separately

Comment: Erm, so what was the point of this question?  Delete it if you don't need help.

Comment: I'm Sorry Mr. Passant... I used broken sentence. Forgive me.  I Tried that originally because I'm familiar with that.  I came to the forums and saw that was the suggestions as well.  This did NOT work.

Comment: Can you grep all of the files in the project for v140 just to be sure? is this a clean build tree, i.e. you're starting with source code only and you don't have any .objs or other generated files left from VS 2015?

Comment: Thanks for Responding Rup. I did a "Clean Solution"... The only thing left is .Log file.  I EVEN deleted that and the associate folder (in the debug folder) and Still the Error shows up.

Comment: What workloads did you install with your new VS 2017 install, and what kind of project are you building?

Comment: Chuck Walbourn - Sorry for the long gap - its 7am here.  The software is a new DAWS.  Libraries;  (A) DSP-Related, (B) Audio Engine/Work flow.  Main Project; UI management.  (A) and (B) Standard C++.  The Main is C++/Cli (Speed up development time using forms).  So Mixed Code.  Installation: Visual Studio Community 2017 - Fairly fast  bandwidth.  Installer (everything installed). I will begin the process of rebuilding this afternoon, and keep the original in case we need to find out why this occurred.

Comment: @HansPassant Curious as to why you felt this was unclear, or un-researched. No one else did.

Comment: I did not vote on this post.  But thanks for reminding me that I should.  Done.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn thanks for the responding

Comment: @Rup thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for being the first to try to assist, my first query here.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY FOLKS - I FOUND A WORK-A-AROUND. This is not a Answer (Because I believe a answer means knowing the cause of the problem and fix it). BUT it will get a person up and running if they run into this problem.

All other project "Solutions" worked. But they only had 1 project. This one had 3 projects. Following the simplest ideas first - I decided to just create a new solution. So I made a new folder, copied the 3 Project folders inside, and created a empty solution. I added existing projects to the solution, re-established the dependencies - and low and behold the Full build was successful (not without a few unrelated issues but it worked).

I will keep the old solution on the system - in case anyone wants me to try another idea, to discover what is going on.

GRIPE: This is stupid. I have new warnings - that didn't exist - and User Controls DLL is acting goofy, which means I have to spend a few days discovering the nuances of 2017 over 2015. Microsoft tells us how to be more efficient - and sometimes neglect doing so themselves when launching new versions. Always some issue with backwards compatibility.

Comment: VS 2017 is a more C++14 conformant compiler than VS 2015, so you are going to see new warnings as the conformance improves. Warnings are good because they point out issues in your code that you can fix or just suppress.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn - thanks for that info - I'm working on it now.  20+ years in software development - I really don't hate Microsoft - but they do know how to push buttons - Have a wonderful day!